# Android app, want to write a text file accessible to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, text, visible

I need to write a text file from my app, when running within or under Eclipse, which
I can then access with a text editor on the development system (windows 7) so I can print it out.

Initially I was hoping to write a file into the RAW directory, because that is directly
accessible inside Eclipse,  but I have read that is not possible. I would like to do 
something like that though. Run my app, use eclipse to view the written file.

Is there a readily available way to do this,
thank you

Comment: did you mean while using emulator? try saving file to emulator's memory amd access it from emulator itself to read the content. that would be the best choice.

Comment: You cant... Save on sd/sd emulation and then copy it from sd to pc  if you need this file only for debug purpose and it is text not binary you can write it to logcat

Comment: Here is my temporary solution until I find a better one. 1. write code in app to create the text file in external storage. 2. email the app to my tablet. 3. run the app. 4. email the text file back to development system. It is clumsy but it works. thanks to Ashu and Selvin for replying.